Cheap way to mix satured fat (beef tallow) with water?
I want to mix beef tallow (satured fat) in water. I want to prepare food or edible product.
I know I must use a emulsifier, but I seen in this video, I can do it by a vacuum chamber.
That means I have to degas the water and it acts like a detergent or surfactant.
The link of the video: https://youtu.be/YJeWklggSpY?si=UDfS92BLanahvS7W
But in another article I read that you have to degas the water and the oil too to make it work.
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/298141754_Worldwide_Mixing_oil_and_water
This actually makes sense, because it would be very easy to sell degassed water as a detergent and just clean with that. Unless someone proves otherwise.
The answer I have so far is, I have to use a surfactant,
emulsifier or a soap. (Correct me if necessary)
I read in another question, in this same forum, that someone said:
"If you are making this at home and do not have access to these kind of products, you can try with organic soap. This is normally oil hydrolyzed with caustic soda (NaOH) and is in essence what is listed as neutralized fatty acid soap."
Best way to mix essential oils with water?
I want to do it as cheaply as possible because I live far from any chemical sales.
Any suggestions? I will read them all.

Two things. Yes, you can make surfactants by hydrolysing fats. But this is not going to be food safe if you don't have access to the right chemicals and it might not work well using beef tallow. Second, we have no evidence that the vacuum method produces product stable in the long term. And you need a vacuum pump to make it which might be as hard to get as known-good food safe surfactants.

The original oleomargarine was water dispersed in beef fat and quicky evolved to vegetable oils. The process was physical mixing until emulsifiers, gums, etc were developed. Research it and read labels for various margarines and shortenings to get ideas about what is done.

Milk is homogenized by pumping though fine orifices; ultrasound can also be used. As for natural soaps, see lecithins.

@matt_black Do you mean surfactants doesn't work with satured fats?

@Nestor No. What I mean is that the surfactants you could make from beef tallow by saponification might not be good surfactants for tallow.

@matt_black hi mate, I understand surfactants can be used with the same principles and techniques as emulsifying oil due both fats and oil are hydrophobic substances

@jimchmst friend, I have read some articles about that, but I don't have clue about the whole process, can you help me with the info? To see that more clear, please

It is mixing at an appropriate speed and temperature. Emulsifiers and gums make it easier. Get a blender, food processor or mixer and experiment. Keep it simple.
